# WPF Custom Control: How to combine 2 controls into 1?

Tags: wpf, controls, textbox, label

I need to create a WPF custom control that will combine a label and a textbox, the label being on the left and the textbox on the right, side by side. I need that kind of control because I'm working on forms that all have the same pattern: label + field to fill. This control would have a LabelContent property and Text property or something like that.

Any advices on how to put that all together?

Thanks

Comment: You should read up on WPF custom control development on the web. There are a lot of resources out there. Then come back here if you need help with something specific while attempting it. 'How to build a custom control?' is too general a question to be reasonably answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a UserControl instead of a CustomControl.  It is designed to allow you to compose other controls into a single, reusable control.